# Editing Goals in SFMC Journeys

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, goals

A client is requesting to change the goal of their in-place journey (it has been running for about 5 months). I've reviewed the documentation on this and have had no luck finding anything regarding changing a goal once it is in place.

Wondering if it's possible to edit a current journey goal, so that the goal metrics can be configured based on different data parameters / attributes. Is editing a current goal / journey possible?

If not, will creating a new version suffice or is an entirely new journey required? TIA!

Answer (score 1):

Just try it out, clicking "new version" does not break anything;

- In a running journey, you cannot manipulate the goal. See details below.
- Once you create a new version, you can reconfigure the goal completely.
- You do not need to recreate the journey from scratch.

The only thing that can be changed in the course of a current journey version is message events. This will not create a new version, but once you click "done" on the email event, it will create a new jobid - if your tracking relies on it, that can be relevant.